# What is Big-O of this setitem method?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o

What is time complexity of this `__setitem__` method for empty dictionary? I think that, .key and .value python methods for dictionary are O(n) ( I read it somewhere) and for loop is also O(n). My guess is O(n)*O(n)*O(n)+O(1) = for loop + if + if body + append. But Im not sure with that "if in for loop body" situation and the .item and .value being O(n).

Please help. It was on my school test. Code is in python.

```
def __setitem__(self,k,v):
  for item in self._table:
    if k == item._key:
      item._value = v
      return
  self._table.append(self._Item(k,v))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `O(len(self._table))` (assuming constructing `self._Item` is `O(1)`) because in the worst case you need to check every element in the `self._table` object.

Both the `if` statement and its body will be `O(1)` in terms of the input because they're atomic operations. Thus, the for-loop's complexity is `O(n) * O(1) * O(1) == O(n)` where `n` is the size of `self._table`.

`append` is an atomic operation for lists, so it's amortized `O(1)`, but if you reach this operation, you've already done `O(n)` work, so it makes the method `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `O(n)`. If you look at complexity, you always imagine to have very large data to put into an algorithm. And for large numbers, `O(n)` is the same as `O(2n)` which would not be a valid notation of big O, because it doesn't make a "big" difference, where as `O(n)` opposed to `O(n^2)` makes a huge difference in computation complexity. Since you only loop through your list once which is `O(n)`, because you loop n-times, and you don't have a nested loop or any expensive calculation with your list there, the overall complexity stays `O(n)`.